# How do I embed all icons within an array?

Tags: ruby, squib

I am trying to get Squib to embed images. I have an excel doc (totm.xlsx) that has fields for Title, Gold, Description, etc. In the Excel doc, most of the cards have :A: or :M: in the description and I would like to replace those with a small SVG icon.

The following code coughs up 'unidentified local method [embed]' and a litany of other errors:

```
require 'squib'

Squib::Deck.new(cards: 54) do
  background color: :white
  data = xlsx file: 'totm.xlsx'

  text str: data['Title'], x: 250, y: 55, font: 'Arial 12'
  text str: data['Gold'], x: 65, y: 65, font: 'Arial 12'
  text(str: data['Description'], x: 65, y: 600, font: 'Arial 12') do [embed]
    embed.svg key: ':A:',   width: 28, height: 28, file: 'battle-axe.svg'
    embed.svg key: ':M:',   width: 28, height: 28, file: 'burning-meteor.svg'
  end
  text str: data['Flavortext'], x: 65, y: 100, font: 'Arial 12'
  text str: data['Type'], x: 65, y: 400, font: 'Arial 12'

   save_sheet prefix: 'totm_sheet_', margin: 75, gap: 5, trim: 37
end
```

In the examples with embedding text, the code always uses a single named string, embed_text, but I would like to call an array of strings.

```
  embed_text = 'Take 1 :tool: and gain 2 :health:.'
  text(str: embed_text, font: 'Sans', font_size: [18, 32, 45],
      x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 300, valign: :bottom,
      align: :left, ellipsize: false, justify: false, hint: :cyan) do |embed|
    embed.svg key: ':tool:',   width: 28, height: 28, file: 'spanner.svg'
    embed.svg key: ':health:', width: 28, height: 28, file: 'glass-heart.svg'
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have brackets around your `[embed]`; as the code example shows, it should be using vertical bars, like `|embed|`.

Comment: Thank you!! Obviously I'm new to Ruby, but thank you so much!
2) I just thought this was funny: but I ordered new glasses today, literally a half hour before I read your comment.